# centre Div/section element in Parallax template

Tags: html, css

so i have this Parallax template that i'm playing around, and i want to add DIV element so after scroll down the DIV will show up, but the problem i'm having that the element moves to the left side and when i zoom out on the browser to something 25% the right hand side is all filled up. How can i correct this?

[Div moves to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJHbT.jpg)

[Zoom out DIV is filled on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNk7.jpg)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Firewatch Parallax in CSS</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__cover">
      <section class="section section_dark">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium, quibusdam? Nobis, delectus,
          commodi,
          fugit amet tempora facere dolores nisi facilis consequatur, odio hic minima nostrum. Perferendis eos earum
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: rgb(199, 27, 187);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* left: 20%; */

}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}


.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
    /* position: fixed; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
  /* left: 20px;
  right: 20px; */
  line-height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  /* left: 80%; */

}

.section_dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a negative margin on the `.parallax` element and it is since it is positioned absolute you should position it 0 units from the left of it's containing element:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.parallax {
  top: 0;
/*   left: 50%; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
/*   margin-left: -1500px; */
}
```

Doing the above alone should center the element but your `img` element will become smaller than the original example you gave. You can fix this by setting the height of the image to a height that you're *happy* with and a width of 100% then using the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to handle the skewing of the aspect ratio:

```
.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%; // set this to what you want
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

See below for a full demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
/*   left: 50%; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
/*   margin-left: -1500px; */
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: rgb(199, 27, 187);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* left: 20%; */

}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}


.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
    /* position: fixed; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
  /* left: 20px;
  right: 20px; */
  line-height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  /* left: 80%; */

}

.section_dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__cover">
      <section class="section section_dark">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium, quibusdam? Nobis, delectus,
          commodi,
          fugit amet tempora facere dolores nisi facilis consequatur, odio hic minima nostrum. Perferendis eos earum
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: this has worked you a star now i'm going and learning what i did wrong thanks again

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting the .parallax class I managed to get this [result](https://codepen.io/janpaulus/pen/YRaKzL).

I removed the negative margin and set the left value to zero to expand the container to full-width.

```
.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* left: 50%; -- removed */
  left: 0; /* added this to make it full-width */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* margin-left: -1500px; -- removed */
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i was thinking that the issue was these but when i removed them i was getting solid color on page. nothing else visible

Answer (score 0):

Commented out some positioning styles applied to the parent parallax div `.parallax` as that was dragging the whole content to the left, off screen.

Tried to center images `.parallax__layer img` by increasing the size to 300% and adding negative left and right margins.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
/*   position: absolute; */
/*   top: 0; */
/*   left: 50%; */
/*   right: 0; */
/*   bottom: 0; */
/*   margin-left: -1500px; */
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width:300%;
  right:-100%;
  left-:-100%;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: rgb(199, 27, 187);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* left: 20%; */

}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}


.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
    /* position: fixed; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
  /* left: 20px;
  right: 20px; */
  line-height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  /* left: 80%; */

}

.section_dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}
```